# How do I use an Ajax.ActionLink without updating the URL

Tags: c#, .net, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I got the following Ajax Actionlink in my cshtml page:

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("Sort By Date",
                "Specific",
                "Events",
                new AjaxOptions {
                    UpdateTargetId="EventListContainer",
                    InsertionMode=InsertionMode.InsertAfter,
                    HttpMethod="GET"
                })
```

And I got these two methods in my controller:

```
public ActionResult Overview(string user)
{
    // return PartialView here
}
```

and

```
public PartialViewResult Specific()
{
    // return PartialView here
}
```

With the following route:

```
routes.MapRoute(
  name: "EventsRoute",
  url: "Events/{user}",
  defaults: new { controller = "Events", action = "Overview" }
);
```

Now, every time I call the Ajax method, `Overview` gets called, with `Specific` Passed inside, instead of the specific method. How can I make sure that Specific() gets called, without updating the url?

Comment: The problem is that route pattern matches `{controller}/{action}`

Answer (score 1):

Something like this. Play around with the ordering.

```
routes.MapRoute(
  name: "EventsSpecificRoute",
  url: "Events/Specific",
  defaults: new { controller = "Events", action = "Specific" }
);
```

Comment: So explicitly create a route for Events/Specific to override the overview route? As my answer above.

Comment: Better, I fixed it for you :). The action is `Specific` **not** `Specifics`.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new Route

```
routes.MapRoute(
  name: "EventSpecific",
  url: "Events/{user}",
  defaults: new { controller = "Events", action = "Specific" }
);
```

when you are using custom routes, i recommend you to `RouteLink` rather than `ActionLink`

```
@Ajax.RouteLink("Sort By Date","EventSpecific", new AjaxOptions {  
                    UpdateTargetId="EventListContainer",
                    InsertionMode=InsertionMode.InsertAfter,
                    HttpMethod="GET"}, null)
```